# Socket.IO malloc: *** error: can't allocate region

Tags: ios, objective-c, socket.io

We are using [this socket.io](https://github.com/nuclearace/Socket.IO-Client-Swift) library every thing went fine util we tried to send images in base64 format.

I receive the folowing error:
malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=xxxxxx) failed (error code=3) *** error: can't allocate region
[image]

is there any way to incress the buffer size ?

I have tried `BUFFER_MAX` to 10000000 but no success.

If i run the same app on the simulator no issue appears but when i run on a real device this crash occur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so the only solution that worked for me ,  thanks to  [@nuclearace](https://github.com/nuclearace) is to wrap all `while` process with `autoreleasepool` as this [comit](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream/pull/289/commits/126c021e61ad77e2eabce326d462abc2af2bcedd)

```
private func dequeueInput() 
  {
    while !inputQueue.isEmpty {
        //code
      }
  }
```

with:

```
private func dequeueInput() 
      {
        while !inputQueue.isEmpty {
           autoreleasepool {
            //code
             }
          }
      }
```